# Javascript maximum path sum in a triangle with prime number check

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I was given this algorithm task:

You will have a triangle input below and you need to find the maximum sum of the numbers according to given rules below;

You will start from the top and move downwards to an adjacent number as in below.

You are only allowed to walk downwards and diagonally.

You can only walk over NON PRIME NUMBERS.

You have to reach at the end of the pyramid as much as possible.

```
           1
          8 4
        2  6  9
      8  5  9  3
```

As you can see this has several paths that fits the rule of NOT PRIME NUMBERS; 1>8>6>9, 1>4>6>9, 1>4>9>9 1 + 8 + 6 + 9 = 24. As you see 1, 8, 6, 9 are all NOT PRIME NUMBERS and walking over these yields the maximum sum.

According to above rules what is the maximum sum of below input? It means please take this pyramid as an input (as file or constants directly inside the code) for your implementation and solve by using it.

```
                              215
                           193 124
                         117 237 442
                       218 935 347 235
                     320 804 522 417 345
                   229 601 723 835 133 124
                 248 202 277 433 207 263 257
               359 464 504 528 516 716 871 182
             461 441 426 656 863 560 380 171 923
           381 348 573 533 447 632 387 176 975 449
         223 711 445 645 245 543 931 532 937 541 444
       330 131 333 928 377 733 017 778 839 168 197 197
    131 171 522 137 217 224 291 413 528 520 227 229 928
  223 626 034 683 839 053 627 310 713 999 629 817 410 121
924 622 911 233 325 139 721 218 253 223 107 233 230 124 233
```

Note that, each node has only two children here (except the most bottom ones). As an example, you can walk from 215 to 124 (because 193 is a prime) then from 124 to either 237 or 442. From 124 you cannot go to 117 because it’s not a direct child of 124.

```
    const isNotPrime = (num) => {
      for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) return true;
      }
      return false;
      }

    function maximumTrianglePathSum(triangle) {

        function distilLastLine() {
          let lastLine = triangle.pop(),
              aboveLine = triangle.pop()
          for (let i = 0; i < aboveLine.length; i++)
          if(isNotPrime(lastLine[i]) && isNotPrime(lastLine[i + 1])){
            aboveLine[i] = Math.max(
              aboveLine[i] + lastLine[i],
              aboveLine[i] + lastLine[i + 1]
            )
          }else if(isNotPrime(lastLine[i]) && !isNotPrime(lastLine[i + 1]) ) {
            aboveLine[i] = aboveLine[i] + lastLine[i]
          }else if(!isNotPrime(lastLine[i]) && isNotPrime(lastLine[i + 1]) ){
            aboveLine[i] = aboveLine[i] + lastLine[i + 1]
          }
          triangle.push(aboveLine)
        }

        do {
          distilLastLine()
        } while (triangle.length > 1)
        return triangle[0][0]
      }

      // testing
      const myArray = [[1],
      [8, 4],
      [2, 6, 9], 
      [8, 5, 9, 3]]
      let theTriangle = [[215],
      [193, 124],
      [117, 237, 442],
      [218, 935, 347, 235],
      [320, 804, 522, 417, 345],
      [229, 601, 723, 835, 133, 124],
      [248, 202, 277, 433, 207, 263, 257],
      [359, 464, 504, 528, 516, 716, 871, 182],
      [461, 441, 426, 656, 863, 560, 380, 171, 923],
      [381, 348, 573, 533, 447, 632, 387, 176, 975, 449],
      [223, 711, 445, 645, 245, 543, 931, 532, 937, 541, 444],
      [330, 131, 333, 928, 377, 733, 17, 778, 839, 168, 197, 197],
      [131, 171, 522, 137, 217, 224, 291, 413, 528, 520, 227, 229, 928],
      [223, 626, 34, 683, 839, 53, 627, 310, 713, 999, 629, 817, 410, 121],
      [924, 622, 911, 233, 325, 139, 721, 218, 253, 223, 107, 233, 230, 124, 233]]

      console.log(maximumTrianglePathSum(myArray))
      console.log(maximumTrianglePathSum(theTriangle))
```

So actually in the first example it prints 23 instead of 24 and the maximum path is 24.

Can somebody help me go through the code and see what's the problem.

Comment: First: Cache the results of `isNotPrime()`

Comment: Second: you forgot `lastLine[i-1]`

Comment: where to put this  lastLine[i-1]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const isPrime = (num) => {
    for (let i = 2; i*i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) return false;
    }    
    return num !== 1;
}

function maximumTrianglePathSum(triangle){
    if(triangle === undefined || triangle.length === 0 || triangle[0].length === 0 || isPrime(triangle[0][0])){
        return 0;
    }
    let sum_values = createEmptyTriangleStructure(triangle);
    for(let k = triangle.length - 1;k >= 0;--k){
        let currentLine = triangle[k];
        for (let i = 0; i < currentLine.length; i++){
            let curr_value = currentLine[i];
            if(isPrime(curr_value)){
                sum_values[k][i] = 0;
            }else if(k === triangle.length - 1){
                sum_values[k][i] = currentLine[i];   
            }else{
                if(i !== 0){
                    sum_values[k][i] = Math.max(sum_values[k][i],curr_value + sum_values[k + 1][i-1]); // left down diagonal
                }                
                sum_values[k][i] = Math.max(sum_values[k][i],curr_value + Math.max(sum_values[k + 1][i],sum_values[k + 1][i + 1]));// check with down value as well as right down diagonal
            }
        }
    }

    return sum_values[0][0];
}

function createEmptyTriangleStructure(triangle){
    let sum = [];
    for(let i=0;i < triangle.length; ++ i){
        sum[i] = [];
        for(let j = 0;j < triangle[i].length; ++ j){
            sum[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

const myArray = [
                    [1],
                    [8, 4],
                    [2, 6, 9], 
                    [8, 5, 9, 3]
                ];
let theTriangle = [
                        [215],
                        [193, 124],
                        [117, 237, 442],
                        [218, 935, 347, 235],
                        [320, 804, 522, 417, 345],
                        [229, 601, 723, 835, 133, 124],
                        [248, 202, 277, 433, 207, 263, 257],
                        [359, 464, 504, 528, 516, 716, 871, 182],
                        [461, 441, 426, 656, 863, 560, 380, 171, 923],
                        [381, 348, 573, 533, 447, 632, 387, 176, 975, 449],
                        [223, 711, 445, 645, 245, 543, 931, 532, 937, 541, 444],
                        [330, 131, 333, 928, 377, 733, 17, 778, 839, 168, 197, 197],
                        [131, 171, 522, 137, 217, 224, 291, 413, 528, 520, 227, 229, 928],
                        [223, 626, 34, 683, 839, 53, 627, 310, 713, 999, 629, 817, 410, 121],
                        [924, 622, 911, 233, 325, 139, 721, 218, 253, 223, 107, 233, 230, 124, 233]
                    ];

console.log(maximumTrianglePathSum(myArray));
console.log(maximumTrianglePathSum(theTriangle));
```

- Your code had many issues. So I changed many things and I will try to explain what I am doing here.
- `isPrime()` checks whether a number is prime or not(takes care of `1` as well).
- See the first `if` condition which handles many corner cases. In that, if the **first number of the first row** is not prime, we return `0` since **you start from the top** and want to walk on non-prime numbers.
- Now, we create a `sum_values` array which will store sums of each row. The structure of this array is same as `triangle` with all locations initialized to `0` with the help of `createEmptyTriangleStructure()`.
- Now, we loop over your triangle from **bottom to top**(which was your idea).
- If we come across a **prime number** in the triangle row, we set that location to `0` in `sum_values` since we can't move below from there.
- If we are going through the last row in the triangle, which is `else if(k === triangle.length - 1)`, then we set them as is since there is no row below this.
- Last, you have been allowed with 3 moves => **down left(diagonally)** , **down** , **down right(diagonally)** => `i - 1` , `i` , `i + 1`.
- So, `[k + 1][i - 1]` is `down left`,`[k + 1][i]` is `down`,`[k + 1][i + 1]` is `down right`.
- So, in the end, we take `max` values among all these and set it as the value of current location `[k][i]`.
- In the end, we return `[0][0]` which is the final value. This is a classic **dynamic programming** problem.
- This can be further optimized in terms of space. Current space complexity is **O(n^2)** but we can reduce this to **O(n)** and I leave that as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of problems.

First, isNotPrime(1) == False, but 1 is not a prime number.

Second, the function distilLastLine forbids walking through nodes if lastLine[i] is prime.  However, lastLine[i] contains the maximum sum from this node onwards (i.e. not the original value in the triangle but a modified value).

Answer (score 0):

This old question was resurrected with a new (since-deleted) answer, and it seems to me that this could be simplified quite a bit, using `reduceRight` to do some dynamic programming.  It might look like this:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  Array .from ({length: hi - lo + 1}, (_, i) => i + lo)

const isPrime = (n) => 
  n > 1 && range (2, Math.floor (Math.sqrt (n))) .every (d => n % d != 0)

const maximumTrianglePathSum = (triangle) =>
  triangle .slice (0, -1) .reduceRight (
    (nextRow, xs) => xs .map (
      (x, i) => isPrime (x) ? -Infinity : x + Math.max (nextRow [i], nextRow [i + 1])
    ),
    triangle .at (-1) .map (n => isPrime (n) ? - Infinity : n)
  ) [0]

const triangle1 = [[1], [8, 4], [2, 6, 9], [8, 5, 9, 3]]
const triangle2 = [[215], [193, 124], [117, 237, 442], [218, 935, 347, 235], [320, 804, 522, 417, 345], [229, 601, 723, 835, 133, 124], [248, 202, 277, 433, 207, 263, 257], [359, 464, 504, 528, 516, 716, 871, 182], [461, 441, 426, 656, 863, 560, 380, 171, 923], [381, 348, 573, 533, 447, 632, 387, 176, 975, 449], [223, 711, 445, 645, 245, 543, 931, 532, 937, 541, 444], [330, 131, 333, 928, 377, 733, 17, 778, 839, 168, 197, 197], [131, 171, 522, 137, 217, 224, 291, 413, 528, 520, 227, 229, 928], [223, 626, 34, 683, 839, 53, 627, 310, 713, 999, 629, 817, 410, 121], [924, 622, 911, 233, 325, 139, 721, 218, 253, 223, 107, 233, 230, 124, 233]]

console .log (maximumTrianglePathSum (triangle1))
console .log (maximumTrianglePathSum (triangle2))
```

Our simplistic `isPrime` function uses a `range` function (e.g. `range (3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`) to test all potential small factors and ensure that none of them divide into our target.

The main function extracts the last row, converts any primes into `-Infinity`, and uses that as the initial accumulator for a `reduceRight`, using a function that calculates each value of the current row by converting primes to `-Infinity` and other numbers into the sum of its value and the maximum of the two values below it.

The steps would look like this:

```
                                       last row: [8, 5, 9, 3]
accumulator: [8, -Infinity, 9, -Infinity]   row: [2, 6, 9]
accumulator: [-Infinity, 15, 18]            row: [8, 4]
accumulator: [23, 22]                       row: [1]
     result: [24]
```

Finally we read off the first and only value of the resulting array.

This has no error-checking.  If the triangle is not configured correctly, the results might be unpredictable.  But I think this technique expresses the problem more simply.