# How to dynamically fill a triangular two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My task requires numerical calculations based on a triangular matrix (modulo numbers don't exceed 9, the size of the array can't be more than 15):

```
 1 2 3 4 5
  7 8 9 0
   4 5 6
    2 3
     1
```

I decided that it would be most convenient to store data in a two-dimensional triangular array.

**UPD**: subsequently, I will need to choose the largest path from any element of the second layer to the very top layer (the path can only go diagonally and cannot go vertically or horizontally up). This is a task similar to the maximum path problem, the solution of which looks the simplest using a [2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682738/javascript-maximum-path-sum-in-a-triangle-with-prime-number-check).

Here I had several problems at once:

1) How to create a triangular array even statically?

Now I am doing something like this:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fillArray(nums, layer) {
    let arr = [];
    for(let k = 0; k < nums.length;) {
        for (let i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
            arr[i] = [];
            for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = nums[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(fillArray(numbers,3));
```

Perhaps this is correct, but it looks too cumbersome and, in addition, it seems to me that I can calculate the layer on the fly. Probably a recursive solution would have looked better here.

2) How to determine when to create a new nested array?

Statically, everything is pretty clear, but if I have an array, let's say it is filled like this: `[ [1], [1, 2], [1, 2] ]` then how to determine the moment of creating a new nested array, that is, fill the current one to this state: `[ [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3] ]` and, for example, if new elements come to input create the following after filling the previous one: `[ [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4] ]`

Comment: is your triangle missing the tens for 10, 11, 12, etc? If not, can you explain the construction? As far as indexing this goes, a 1D array should be pretty easy in terms of knowing what "height" you're at based on the linear index because of how many numbers fit in each 'row' of the triangle.

Comment: What's your input? What's your output? I got lost in the explanation, as you're re-defining terms (e.g. *triangular matrix*)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I originally wanted to store everything in a 1D array, but it seemed to me less convenient in terms of determining the level of finding the number. The task does not specify what numbers should be, but just such an example is given. I suppose, as a simplification, they took the fact that the modulus of a number cannot be greater than 9.

Comment: @GalAbra any numbers / array of numbers with a modulus not exceeding 9 are fed to the input. A 2D array is expected at the output, where the numbers are stored in the input order, but converted to 2D according to the principle that in each next nested array, more on `j + 1` numbers are stored than in the previous one. Thus, a kind of triangular matrix is obtained.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The thing is that I then need to draw an array on the screen in a formatted form. If the number were of any size, it would be a little more complicated. At the same time, it is still necessary to solve a problem similar to the problem of finding the maximum path, which is why I decided to store everything in a 2D format (here the idea arises of storing in a square array with filled zeros at the place of the passes, but I'm not sure).

Comment: I'd still use a 1D array but the real question is "what do you need to _do_ with the numbers". Because how you store the numbers is basically irrelevant as long as you can perform the operations required. "drawing the triangle" is basically the least interesting thing you could possibly do here: you just count 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. elements and "go to the next line" when you've seen `n` elements at depth `n`.

Comment: (and if you need to resolve "a 1d index to its depth", https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455511/formula-for-the-nth-term-of-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4-5 has you covered)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for a long time I tried to understand the essence of the problem which is described mathematically, but did not understand. I just realized that this is the same solution that 6502 provided. I need to count the weight of the branches. That is, over each element in the triangle that I presented as an example, there are exactly 2 elements and it is necessary to calculate which one is heavier (over which there are more elements).

Comment: Based on this, it will then be necessary to swap the elements with each other, because I will remove the very first one and it will be necessary to move the element from the top to its position and so on in depth to the last layer. The result will be the most "heavy" way. So I know how to do this on the basis of a 2D array, but I can not imagine how to do it in a 1D array.

Comment: So don't just tell me that: remember to update your post so that you're telling _everyone_ that. It's important to make sure to put [all relevant details in your question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197419/discussion-between-nikita-kobtsev-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like shown in the snippet. But it is definitely slower than a for loop and does not use recursion...Would be interesting to measure performance of `.reduce()` vs. a recursive solution like @VLAZ posted.

What the code below does is to fill the layers until they are full and then create a new one based on the length of the previous one + 1:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];

let layer = 0;
const fillArray = input => input.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if ( acc.length ) {    
    if ((acc[layer] || []).length !== acc[layer-1].length+1) {
      // fill current child-array until full
      acc[layer] = (acc[layer] || []).concat(num);
    } else {
      // start next child-array with current number
      layer++;
      acc[layer] = [num];
    }
  } else {
    // initialize with first child-array
    layer++;
    acc = [[num]];
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(fillArray(numbers));
```

A more "traditional" way of writing the function same function:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];

let layer = 0;
function fillArray(input) {
  return input.reduce(function(acc, num) {
    if ( acc.length ) {    
      if ( (acc[layer] || []).length !== acc[layer-1].length+1 ) {
        // fill current child-array until full
        acc[layer] = (acc[layer] || []).concat(num);
      } else {
        // start next child-array with current number
        layer++;
        acc[layer] = [num];
      }
    } else {
      // initialize with first child-array
      layer++;
      acc = [[num]];
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(fillArray(numbers));
```

Comment: I am not very good at arrow functions. How can I convert this to a function inside a class?

Comment: @Nikita Kobtsev updated the answer with a more traditionally written version =)!

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why an error `TypeError: input.reduce is not a function` occurs using the option with the arrow function as a class property?

Comment: couldn't tell without seeing the complete code...sorry

Comment: oh, I understood.This error was with both solutions. The fact is that I out of habit passed a set of numbers, not an array. Is it possible to convert numbers to an array when calling a function using `Array.from(input)`?

Comment: you mean something like `function(1,2,3,4,5)`  so all the numbers become an array within the function? Yeah, technically you can do that by making the `input` argument a "rest" parameter, like this `...input` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: I know this type of parameter, but I did not understand how to use it in arrow functions. I just changed `input` to `(... input)` after the first equals and `console.log(nums)` became completely empty

Comment: you need to remove the space inbetween ... and `input`

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was only a typo here, everything is fine in my code and this time I forgot to omit the square brackets when passing the parameters. Now everything works, thank you very much again!

Comment: Is it possible to change the code so that it adds elements to the array instead of spaces in the order they appear in the input array (some elements = ' ')? I tried using `array.filter(char => char !==  ' ')`, but in this case the order of the elements changes, but it's important for me to keep the order.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197501/discussion-between-nikita-kobtsev-and-exside).

Answer (score 2):

If your computation is using the triangular matrix randomly you could compute the row/col index explicitly:

```
function row_col_from_index(i) {
    let row = 0.5 * ((8*i + 1)**0.5 - 1),
        col = i - row*(row+1)/2;
    return [row, col];
}

function index_from_row_col(row, col) {
    return row*(row+1)/2 + col;
}
```

then you could create the needed row lazily in the matrix when you need it

```
let matrix = [];
...
let [row, col] = row_col_from_index(i);
(matrix[row]||(matrix[row]=[]))[col] = data;
```

The "magic" formula for row/col from index was computed by solving

```
x*(x+1)/2 = n
```

[image: solution procedure for solving x*(x+1)/2=n]

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand your solution a bit. Also, I'm sorry, but I just realized that I forgot to say that the modulus of numbers does not exceed 9 and that the array cannot be larger than 15 in size. So the calculations are based on a not entirely random array.

Comment: @NikitaKobtsev: for 15 values only just creating a table would be reasonable: `row = [0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4], col=[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4];`. Then you can use `matrix[row[i]][col[i]] = x`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this will help me in drawing the values on the screen? I just don’t understand why this might be reasonable, I added a little explanation to the post in the comments. Maybe it will become a little clearer or I don't fully understand the essence of the solution.

Comment: @NikitaKobtsev: those are the formulas that given an index tell you the row/col and vice-versa. The row/col to index is rather obvious, the inverse one a little less so that's why I only wrote that one before.

Comment: I just realized your decision! You accepted that the matrix in that form comes to the input of the function. But I didn’t mean it. I just said that I have to work with data in this form (maybe I didn’t write like that, but that’s what was meant).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can employ a recursive algorithm here and stop when there are no more values to draw from, otherwise take an ever growing slice from the beginning of the input array and then use what is left next time:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fillArray(nums, result = [], size = 1) {
  if (nums.length === 0) return result;
  
  const currentItem = nums.slice(0, size);
  const remainder = nums.slice(size);
  result.push(currentItem);
   
  return fillArray(remainder, result, size + 1);
}

console.log(fillArray(numbers));
```

This can be further shortened to just two lines, if needed

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fillArray(nums, result = [], size = 1) {
  if (nums.length === 0) return result;
   
  return fillArray(
    nums.slice(size), 
    [...result, nums.slice(0, size)], 
    size + 1
  );
}

console.log(fillArray(numbers));
```